# array + constant expression in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, constants

I want to get n from the user and put it on array expression but in visual studio 2017 a getting error ( expression must have a constant value ), I saw other compilers work with that perfectly.
I thought I could use new or a pointer but those don't work too.
I know there is similar topic for it (i couldn't understand them and match them with my problem ) but it would be great if someone writes correct code for me.
thanks.

```
  int n;
    cout <<"Enter n:" ;
    cin >> n;
    int a[n];    //recive error for n (expression must have a constant value)

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
         a[i]=rand() % 100;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)        
        cout<<setw(5)<< a[i];
```

Comment: *"but it would be great if someone writes correct code for me"* - `std::vector<int> a(n);`

Comment: @StoryTeller... `std::vector<int> a(n)`;.

Comment: *"I thought I could use new or a pointer but those don't work too."* - What code did you try for that?

Comment: @sgarizvi - Those pesky pages with their refresh rate ;)

Answer (score 2):

In C++, arrays must have fixed sizes. You can not have a plain array whose size depends on a run-time value. This is why the compiler complains that `n` is not constant in `int a[n];`.

You should use `std::vector` instead: `std::vector<int> a(n);` will create a vector that can hold `n` elements. The rest of your code can stay the same.

Comment: thx for fast replay. works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

*"I thought I could use new or a pointer but those don't work too."*...Did You really do that?

first solution is as some of the answers suggested you can use a vector.

But if you wanted to use pointers and new (which is the only way to do it as an array declaration need a constant size at declaration) you can use the following:

```
int n;
cout <<"Enter n:" ;
cin >> n;
int *a;    //recive error for n (expression must have a constant value)
a = new int [n];  // <--- this will allocate the memory to create an array of size n.

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
     a[i]=rand() % 100;

for(int i=0;i<n;i++)        
    cout<<setw(5)<< a[i];
```

Remember to use delete after new. (delete [] a);

Comment: thanks for showing how I must use pinter and new in a correct way, it really helped me.